# Use json in the filter

Tags: json, flutter

Hi guys I have an api I use that responds like this:
[responds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCJNL.png)

```
{
"RAW": {
    "BTC": {
        "USD": {
            "TYPE": "5",
            "MARKET": "CCCAGG",
            "FROMSYMBOL": "BTC",
            "TOSYMBOL": "USD",
            "FLAGS": "1026",
            "PRICE": 41091.49,
            "LASTUPDATE": 1649873443,
            "MEDIAN": 41085.18,
            "LASTVOLUME": 0.001056,
            "LASTVOLUMETO": 43.38595008,
```

Now to convert and use it in darts (modeling) we have to do the mapping operation, right? Does anyone know how to do this when this response is nested! I did it, but I know it's not right

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR3O7.png)

```
 class CryptoEntity {
 final String basecode;
 // final String targetcod;
 final int price;
 final int volume;
 final int change;

 CryptoEntity.fromjason(Map<String, dynamic> jason)
  : basecode = jason['FROMSYMBOL'],
    // targetcod = jason['target'],
    price = jason['PRICE'],
    volume = jason['VOLUMEDAY'],
    change = jason['LASTVOLUME'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) and [json serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation) for code generation, it is good for the long term development but this requires basic knowledge in flutter.
2. Use [Online JSON to Dart converter](https://www.webinovers.com/web-tools/json-to-dart-convertor), this site generates null safety dart class. With this solution, all you need is to change the class names after each conversion manually, and note for the `fromJson` factory constructor method and `toJson` class method.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class CryptoEntity {
 final String? basecode; // ? => means that this field can be null
 // final String targetcod;
 final int? price;
 final int? volume;
 final int? change;

 //constroctor
CryptoEntity(this.basecode, this.price, .. );

factory CryptoEntity.fromjason(Map<String, dynamic> jason){

return CryptoEntity(

 price = jason['PRICE'],
    volume = jason['VOLUMEDAY'],
    change = jason['LASTVOLUME'];
);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can turn the json into an object**

```
import 'dart:convert';

MyModel myModelFromMap(String str) => MyModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String myModelToMap(MyModel data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class MyModel {
    MyModel({
        required this.raw,
    });

    Raw raw;

    factory MyModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyModel(
        raw: Raw.fromMap(json["RAW"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "RAW": raw.toMap(),
    };
}

class Raw {
    Raw({
        required this.btc,
    });

    Btc btc;

    factory Raw.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Raw(
        btc: Btc.fromMap(json["BTC"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "BTC": btc.toMap(),
    };
}

class Btc {
    Btc({
        required this.usd,
    });

    Usd usd;

    factory Btc.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Btc(
        usd: Usd.fromMap(json["USD"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "USD": usd.toMap(),
    };
}

class Usd {
    Usd({
        required this.type,
        required this.market,
        required this.fromsymbol,
        required this.tosymbol,
        required this.flags,
        required this.price,
        required this.lastupdate,
        required this.median,
        required this.lastvolume,
        required this.lastvolumeto,
    });

    String type;
    String market;
    String fromsymbol;
    String tosymbol;
    String flags;
    double price;
    int lastupdate;
    double median;
    double lastvolume;
    double lastvolumeto;

    factory Usd.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Usd(
        type: json["TYPE"],
        market: json["MARKET"],
        fromsymbol: json["FROMSYMBOL"],
        tosymbol: json["TOSYMBOL"],
        flags: json["FLAGS"],
        price: json["PRICE"].toDouble(),
        lastupdate: json["LASTUPDATE"],
        median: json["MEDIAN"].toDouble(),
        lastvolume: json["LASTVOLUME"].toDouble(),
        lastvolumeto: json["LASTVOLUMETO"].toDouble(),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "TYPE": type,
        "MARKET": market,
        "FROMSYMBOL": fromsymbol,
        "TOSYMBOL": tosymbol,
        "FLAGS": flags,
        "PRICE": price,
        "LASTUPDATE": lastupdate,
        "MEDIAN": median,
        "LASTVOLUME": lastvolume,
        "LASTVOLUMETO": lastvolumeto,
    };
}
```

**You can use it like this**

```
MyModel myModel = myModelFromMap(jsonDecode(json));
```

https://app.quicktype.io/